# Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg not compressing video from Nugat 7.1

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ffmpeg, xamarin.android, compression

We have been using [Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg](https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg) successfully for some time to compress videos, it works up to Nougat 7.0 (API level 24), but it doesn't seem to support the latest Android versions:

- Oreo | 8.1.0 | API level 27
- Oreo | 8.0.0 | API level 26
- Nougat | 7.1 | API level 25

Package Name: [Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg v1.0.32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.FFmpeg/)

We use the following options:

```
string[] cmds = new string[] {
  "-y",
  "-i",
  inputFilepath,
  "-strict", "experimental",
  "-vcodec", "libx264",
  "-preset", "ultrafast",
  "-crf","30", "-acodec","aac", "-ar", "44100" ,
  "-q:v", "20",
  "-vf",
  "mp=eq2=1:1.68:0.3:1.25:1:0.96:1",
  ouputFile,
};

string cmdParams = string.Join(" ", cmds);

FFMpeg.Xamarin.FFMpegLibrary.Run(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, cmdParams, loggerAction);
```

We've searched for alternatives, but nothing seems obvious. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or suggest an alternative library/approach (even a paid for one)?

**EDIT:**

We note a message on the read me [read me](https://github.com/neurospeech/xamarin-android-ffmpeg) which states:

> For Android 6.0 onwards, use Xamarin.Android.MP4Transcoder Android 6.0
>   onwards, text relocations are strictly prohibited, many source files
>   used in ffmpeg use text relocations so ffmpeg will never run on future
>   android builds unless they rewrite large library and replace them with
>   alternative of text relocations. For this, only alternative is to use
>   Android's native Mp4 transcoder.

However, we've tried using:

```
 Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder.For720pFormat().ConvertAsync
 Xamarin.MP4Transcoder.Transcoder.For960x540Format().ConvertAsync
```

but this doesn't solve our requirements for compression.